# Passing Function Variable

Tags: excel, vba, function

I need my code to return the randomized string and its returning nothing. Ive included the code to make it easier. I hope this helps.

Everything is running and the msg is coming up but variables dna1 and dna2 are empty.

```
Dim lengthDNA As Integer

Sub dna()
    Dim str As String, dna1 As String, dna2 As String
    Dim x As Long
    
    lengthDNA = InputBox("Enter the length of DNA sequences (10-250)")
    
    dna1 = RandInteger("ACGT")
    dna2 = RandInteger("ACGT")
    
    MsgBox ("DNA Sequence 1 is: " & dna1 & Chr(13) & "DNA Sequence 2 is: " & dna2), vbInformation
End Sub



Public Function RandInteger(strRandom As String) As String
    dnaBank = Array("A", "C", "G", "T")
    
    For x = 1 To lengthDNA
        Randomize
        strRandom = strRandom & dnaBank(Int((UBound(dnaBank) - LBound(dnaBank) + 1) * Rnd + LBound(dnaBank)))
    Next x
End Function
```

Comment: You need `RandInteger = strRandom` before `End function` or your function never returns a value.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use global variables if you don't need to. Declare your variables as local as possible and as close tho their first use as possible. If you need ot submit a variable to another function/sub submit it as parameter.

Choose good names for your variables and functions. `RandInteger` for example is very confusing. You name your function something with `Integer` but it returns a `String` (text). Instead give it a meaningful name eg `CreateRandomDNA()` and submit the `Length` you want the DNA to be as parameter.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub dna()
    Dim lengthDNA As Long
    
    ' get DNA length from user input, allow user to press cancel
    Dim ReturnValue As Variant
    ReturnValue = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the length of DNA sequences (10-250)", Type:=1) 'Type:=1 Allow numbers only
    If VarType(ReturnValue) = vbBoolean And ReturnValue = False Then
        'user pressed cancel
        Exit Sub
    Else
        lengthDNA = ReturnValue
    End If
    
    Dim dna1 As String
    dna1 = CreateRandomDNA(lengthDNA)
    
    Dim dna2 As String
    dna2 = CreateRandomDNA(lengthDNA)
    
    MsgBox "DNA Sequence 1 is: " & dna1 & vbCrLf & "DNA Sequence 2 is: " & dna2, vbInformation
End Sub



Public Function CreateRandomDNA(ByVal Length As Long) As String
    Dim dnaBank As Variant
    dnaBank = Array("A", "C", "G", "T")
    
    Randomize
    
    Dim strRandom As String
    Dim x As Long
    For x = 1 To Length
        strRandom = strRandom & dnaBank(Int((UBound(dnaBank) - LBound(dnaBank) + 1) * Rnd + LBound(dnaBank)))
    Next x
    
    CreateRandomDNA = strRandom  ' return random string to function
End Function
```

---

If you need to create different strings like DNA, RNA, Amino Acids (for proteins) you can do that in one function too:

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum BioCodeType
    bctDNA
    bctRNA
    bctAminoAcidSingleLetter
    bctAminoAcidMultiLetter
End Enum

Public Sub dna()
    Dim sequenceLength As Long
    
    Dim ReturnValue As Variant
    ReturnValue = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the length of DNA sequences (10-250)", Type:=1) 'Type:=1 Allow numbers only
    If VarType(ReturnValue) = vbBoolean And ReturnValue = False Then
        'user pressed cancel
        Exit Sub
    Else
        sequenceLength = ReturnValue
    End If
    
    Dim dna As String
    dna = CreateRandomBioString(sequenceLength, bctDNA)
    
    Dim rna As String
    rna = CreateRandomBioString(sequenceLength, bctRNA)
    
    Dim aminoSingle As String
    aminoSingle = CreateRandomBioString(sequenceLength, bctAminoAcidSingleLetter)
    
    Dim aminoMulti As String
    aminoMulti = CreateRandomBioString(sequenceLength, bctAminoAcidMultiLetter)
    
    MsgBox "DNA Sequence is: " & dna & vbCrLf & _
           "RNA Sequence is: " & rna & vbCrLf & _
           "Amino Acid Sequence (single letter) is: " & aminoSingle & vbCrLf & _
           "Amino Acid Sequence (multi letter) is: " & aminoMulti & vbCrLf _
           , vbInformation
End Sub



Public Function CreateRandomBioString(ByVal Length As Long, ByVal BioCode As BioCodeType) As String
    Dim Bank As Variant
    Dim Seperator As String
    
    Select Case BioCode
        Case bctDNA
            Bank = Array("A", "C", "G", "T")
    
        Case bctRNA
            Bank = Array("A", "C", "G", "U")
            
        Case bctAminoAcidSingleLetter
            Bank = Array("A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "E", "Q", "G", "H", "I", "L", "K", "M", "F", "P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V")
    
        Case bctAminoAcidMultiLetter
            Bank = Array("ALA", "ARG", "ASN", "ASP", "CYS", "GLU", "GLN", "GLY", "HIS", "ILE", "LEU", "LYS", "MET", "PHE", "PRO", "SER", "THR", "TRP", "TYR", "VAL")
            Seperator = "-"
    End Select

    Dim bankSize as Long
    bankSize = UBound(Bank) - LBound(Bank) + 1

    Dim bankMin As Long
    bankMin = LBound(Bank)

    Randomize
    
    Dim strRandom As String
    Dim x As Long
    For x = 1 To Length
        strRandom = strRandom & IIf(strRandom <> vbNullString, Seperator, vbNullString) & Bank(Int(bankSize * Rnd + bankMin))
    Next x
    
    CreateRandomBioString = strRandom
End Function
```

and it will return something like

[image]

Comment: As far as dnaBank is obviously fixed, I would also remove all those UBound & Co. I guess `dnaBank(Int(4*Rng))` is enough, isn't it?

Comment: @Vitalizzare true, if it is fixed you can do that. If you might want to take this out and expose it as a parameter you would want to keep it. • What you definitely can do is take this calculation `Int((UBound(dnaBank) - LBound(dnaBank) + 1)` out of the loop, so it is only calculated once and saved in a variable. That will save some calculations at least.

Comment: @Pen Yes, right. It's just specifics of this task. By the way, do you know whether it is possible to control rounding rules for parameters?

Comment: @Vitalizzare what do you mean by *"rounding rules for parameters"*?

Comment: @Pen Well I thought dnaBank(4*Rng) should do the job. But it looks like floating point numbers are **rounded up** when cast to integers, e.g. dnaBank(3.9) will run like dnaBank(4). I'm looking for a source to read about parameter conversion rules before executing functions. Can you help?

Comment: @Vitalizzare That is because of implicit conversion of a `Double` or `Single` value which `3.9` is into a `Integer` or `Long`. Because the array `dnaBank` needs a index that is a positive integer, it casts the decimal into an integer. That is done by the same functions as `cInt` or `cLng` and they will round. As you can read in the documentation [Type conversion functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions) where it says *"fractions are rounded"*.

Comment: @Vitalizzare Note that the OP used `Int` which does not round but will remove the fractional part of number and return the resulting integer value. See [Int, Fix functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/int-fix-functions)

Answer (score 2):

No return value is ever specified for `RandInteger`.

Add `RandInteger = strRandom` as the  last statement of the function..

**Note**

You might also want to check other portions of the code:

- It does not make much sense to pass a fixed prefix string to the randomizer function. Instead make the target length of the random string a parameter.
- `Randomize` initializes VBAs random number generator. It should be called once for the whole program instead of before every call to `Rnd` as it is now.

Comment: I removed randomize underneath the DNA array. That makes so much sense, but im not sure how to pass the length as a parameter.